# When to use that or those?

Tags: word-usage

I was reading and I found this sentence, "Some kinds of travel, such as ***that*** made by auto, bus, or train incur both time and monetary costs; other trips such as ***those*** made on foot, involve an expense primarily of time." Why is That used in the first one and Those used in the second? Or were they interchangeable here?

Comment: "that" is for singular, "those" is for plural

Answer (score 1):

"**Travel**" as used in the sentence is an **uncountable** noun, while "**trips**" is a **countable** one and is in **plural** form.

- Use *that* to refer to a countable noun in singular form or an uncountable one.
- Use *those* to refer to a countable one in plural form.